# Status code 503 on Changing Uber Request status to in_progress (Sand-box API)

Tags: uber-api

Since yesterday, I am getting the response

503 Service Unavailable

```
{ status code: 503, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 78;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Fri, 24 Jul 2015 08:36:24 GMT";
Server = nginx;
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
"X-Uber-App" = "uberex-sandbox";
"X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";}
```

while changing the status of Uber Request API to in_progress

I have tested some days ago it was working fine. but since yesterday I am getting such weird response, did any body faced this.

Note: I have tested the `accepted` and `arriving` status are working fine and returns the valid response.

Answer (score 0):

503 normally means the problem is at server side. So I guess you could wait a while and see if Uber server would come around. BTW, how did you test different statuses like `accepted` and `arriving` with the sandbox? Because I can only see `processing` after I made a request and if I made estimate request further more, `processing` is all I got.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am waiting since 2 days to for server response to my in_progress. I don't know why server not respond my in_progress call only. BTW you can change the status of your ride manually. Uber provides this in sandbox mode. please visit https://developer.uber.com/v1/sandbox/

Comment: Oh, cool, I didn't notice that part before, thanks! I will try it out. And I will let you know if I can get through the `in_progress`.

Comment: yes please check on your side either in_progress working for you?

Comment: @Hussain, I got 405 code with all the statuses, did you meet this before?

Comment: 405 status: The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.

Comment: again in_progress is not working, what the hell is going on.